# Synchronize Batch Jobs across multiple Application Instances

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am writing a spring batch application which should only run one Job Instance at a time. This should also be true if multiple application instances are started. Sadly, the jobs can’t be parallelized and are invoked at random.

So, what I am looking for is a spring boot configuration which allows me to synchronize the job execution within one processor as well as in the distributed case. I have already found some approaches like the JobLauncherSynchronizer (https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch-admin/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/admin/launch/JobLauncherSynchronizer.html) but all the solutions I have found work either only on one processor or protect just a fraction of the job execution.

Is there any spring boot configuration which prevents multiple concurrent executions of the same job, even across multiple concurrently running application instances (which share the same database)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I made a POC that can help you https://github.com/jamataran/spring-batch-scale

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any spring boot configuration which prevents multiple concurrent executions of the same job, even across multiple concurrently running application instances (which share the same database)?

Not to my knowledge. If you really want to have a global synchronization at the job level (ie a single job instance at a time), you need a global synchronizer like the `JobLauncherSynchronizer` you linked to.